# NodeJS replace like values in an array with another value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to replace all of the same values in an array with a unique token.

For example: 
Array =

```
[{ name: 'Dave', groupid: '1' },
  { name: 'Bob', groupid: '1' },
  { name: 'Jessica', groupid: '2' },
  { name: 'Natalie', groupid: '3' }]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[{ name: 'Dave', groupid: 'fj782' },
  { name: 'Bob', groupid: 'fj782' },
  { name: 'Jessica', groupid: 'wi283' },
  { name: 'Natalie', groupid: 'ivh29' } ]
```

Here's what I use to generate the unique token:

```
var uniqueGroupid =
      Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(2, 5) +
      Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(2, 5);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map` object to accumulate unique groupid's and replace them as you go:

```js
    let data = [{ name: 'Dave', groupid: '1' },
      { name: 'Bob', groupid: '1' },
      { name: 'Jessica', groupid: '2' },
      { name: 'Natalie', groupid: '3' }];
      
    function makeNewGroupId() {
      return Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(2, 5) +
      Math.random()
        .toString(36)
        .substring(2, 5);
    }
    
    // map object where we store original groupid as key and new groupid as value
    let uniqueGroupIds = new Map();

    for (let obj of data) {
        // see if we already have this groupid in the Map
        let newId = uniqueGroupIds.get(obj.groupid);
        // if not, make a new group id
        if (!newId) {
            newId = makeNewGroupId();
            // save this new groupid in our map
            uniqueGroupIds.set(obj.groupid, newId);
        }
        // update the object with the newId
        obj.groupid = newId;
    }
    
    console.log(data);
```

The function `makeNewGroupId()` can be whatever function you want to coin a new and unique groupId with.

Comment: That's almost perfect, for some reason it's replacing all groupid's with the same unique token. Is there a way to replace them with the same unique token where the groupid is the same? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @CameronRose - I fixed a typo where it was referring to `data.groupid` when it should have been referring to `obj.groupid`.  You can actually run the snippet in the answer now and see that it works.

Comment: Sorry just saw this. Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Taught me something new too :)

Answer (score 1):

jfriend00's answer is correct but since you said you want to replace them with a **unique** value, your function makeNewGroupId() as is won't cut it I'm afraid. There's no check on whether the value already exists. Odds are good that you'll get a different value each time if your array has 1000 or 10000 values. But what if it contains 100000 values? You're better off with something like [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid) since you're using nodejs.

```
var uniqid = require('uniqid');

function makeNewGroupId(groupid) {
      return uniqid(groupid + "-") //adding the groupid as suffix
    }
```

```
1-d8gnw84rgjz79s2yw
```

Comment: Not something I considered due to the small numbers i'm working with but definitely adding this in for future proofing! Thanks!